Convert UWP To WinUI 3 - Missing EntryPoint When Attempting To Run Application
First I get error that I must Deploy the application.  I have Deploy check box checked in Configuration Manager but have worked around this by choosing the Project in solution explorer, right click and choose Deploy from menu.
I still get error: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(42,10): error 0x80080204: Cannot register the PlcWorkOrderUwp-Deploy-Package_2.1.18.0_x64__pemvxjdcr8wxc package because the extension is missing an EntryPoint or StartPage attribute.   PlcWorkOrderUwp
I have run out of articles to review for an answer.  I am providing a picture of the pieces I believe could be part of the problem.  Based on my reading I have everything in place so not sure what to try next.
I removed the /bin and /obj folders.  I reviewed the App.g.is.cs generated code.  This was a UWP app with a Package project and I moved the Package Manifest and Images to the WinUI project and removed the Packaging project to make it a single project WinUI 3 packaged project.
I am running from my local drive, there is no encryption, the Package Manifest is in the project.  I did not choose a project template of Packaged Project but used the Upgrade Assistant to convert my UWP application.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/upgrade-assistant
Another caveat of the UWP project was separate projects to use the Excel and Outlook interop that I could not use from the UWP application.  I have removed these projects but it appears some remnants may still be in the Package Manifest .XML file under Extensions not sure why these are still being created with the projects removed from the WinUI 3 application.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">
  <Identity Name="PlcWorkOrderUwp-Deploy-Package" Publisher="CN=PlcWorkOrderUwp_Trusted4" Version="2.1.18.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>PlcWorkOrderUwp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>PlcWorkOrderSystem</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.22000.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="PLC Work Order - WORKS" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Plc Work Order Uwp Application" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" Square310x310Logo="Assets\LargeTile.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\SmallTile.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\PLC_WorksSplash.jpg" BackgroundColor="#88ABA0" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Launcher\Launcher.exe">
          <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
            <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="Excel" Parameters="/excel" />
            <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="Outlook" Parameters="/outlook" />
          </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
        </desktop:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
          <uap:AppService Name="ExcelInteropService" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
          <uap:AppService Name="OutlookInteropService" />
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>


The error message is "the extension is missing an EntryPoint or StartPage attribute. PlcWorkOrderUwp", have you checked the EntryPoint in Package.appxmanifest?

Thank you for a reply.  I attempted to include a picture of the relevant "parts" but it did not work so I will explain them best I can.  On the Package Manifest it has $targetentrypoint$ as the Entry Point.  In the .csproj file it contains this - PlcWorkOrderUwp.Program.  In the App.g.i.cs generated code I find the public static class Program with what appears to be the valid code to start the application.  It appears all the pieces are in place to launch the application.  However it is converted UWP did something get missed.

A question for someone that may know.  I used the full trust launch capabilities in my UWP project to launch Excel and Outlook.  Having to inspect the code that starts a WinUI application it appears to me it is a UWP application running as full trust in Windows?  This is how it is pulled out of the sandboxing of a UWP application?  Maybe I can actually use the UWP knowledge I gained with WinUI and not feel like I am starting over again.

Full trust apps don't run in a sandbox, you can use FullTrustProcessLauncher to activate the full-trust Win32 component of an application from a Universal Windows app component in the same application package.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/upgrade-assistant#follow-up-manual-migration Did you modify your Package.appxmanifest according to the documentation? Could you please provide the complete Package.appxmanifest to help us further check the problem for you?

I replaced a portion of the Package Manifest in the original post with the complete manifest.  I have read a lot of documentation trying to resolve this issue so not sure the documentation you are referring to.  This is the article I used the most - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/upgrade-assistant

IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap" should contain "desktop“ IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap desktop". Is ”Launcher\Launcher.exe“ compiled and used Process.Start to start the Excel or Outlook?

The Launcher program was used by the UWP application to launch Excel and Outlook interop.  It is not needed by WinUI3 since it runs full trust is my understanding.  These projects have been removed but these remnants remain in the manifest.  I was reluctant to remove them but it makes sense to me I should since no longer needed fro WinUI3.

Made the change to the IgnorableNamespaces entry.  Should I also remove -   
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />


Removing the Extension for the Launcher program has resolved the Deploy and Entry Point issue.  I was reluctant because I did not writ this "code" and I removed the projects associated with it so thought it would be ignored.  I have now run into an issue because I used UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs.User and my code is choking on this but it is my code so it must be running the application.   Your help is much appreciated I thought it was better to get some instruction than to start deleting "code" I was not sure of.

I can see I still need the Capability Name="runFullTrust" so answers my question.

"These projects have been removed but these remnants remain in the manifest." Is Launcher.exe deleted?

Removing the reference to the Launcher, Excel and Outlook interop in the Package Manifest resolved the deployment issues I am able to run the application.  I am finding more issues when I run it this is more work than it should be to convert from UWP to WinUI.  The only reason I used UWP was because I thought it would be maintained for a while I really hope WinUI will be around for a while to make this effort worth it.

https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/blob/master/UWP_FullTrust_2/Package/Package.appxmanifest This sample may help.

The effort to convert my UWP app to WinUI has been problematic.  Even simple stuff like changing the mouse pointer from Arrow to Wait has me finding and changing a lot of code and reclassing controls which has not worked so far.  Using the Upgrade Assistant led me to believe it would convert without having to recode basic stuff but it did not.  I want my app to be updated with the most recent .Net but how much do I need to fix to an application that works great as UWP.  My NavigationView Style that works fine in UWP does not in WinUI.  Stuff I should not need to "fix"

Migrating a complex project from UWP to winui3 is not a simple process. Even after using .NET Upgrade Assistant, it still requires a lot of manual operations. It is recommended that you migrate step by step according to the function or page. You can refer to the official sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/case-study-1

Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
ErrorCode: -2147467259
HResult: -2147467259
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: ""
Source: "WinRT.Runtime"
StackTrace: "   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.g__Throw|39_0(Int32 hr)\r\n   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverridesMethods.MeasureOverride(IObjectReference _obj, Size availableSize)\r\n   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n

I am able to compile and deploy.  I can make a selection from the menu.  The EF - DAL returns me a list of objects.  I set the ItemsSource of the grid to the List<> and based on tracking in debug mode, the page should now appear.  Instead I get the above exception in my Unhandled Exception code.  Based on the Stack Trace it appears to be attempting to render the page.  Using the ErrorCode I get information on it being some type of Excel error.  I am at a dead end again.

I attempted to navigate to a different Page.  It makes it through the constructor logic put throws the same error before getting to the Page Load event code.  The first page makes it through the Page Load before throwing the error.  I am running out of stuff to try and figure out what is going on and why Pages navigated to from the Main Page throw the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Still have not figured out the problem but still trying.  I see an article about a new conversion process for .Net 9 maybe I will have more success using it.  I learned some things attempting this conversion that will help me with the next.  I will remove my full trust projects I needed to access Excel and Outlook before attempting to convert.  And know I am going to have to find all my Dialog Windows and update the XamlRoot property to the App Window handle.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/preview-uwp-support-for-dotnet-9-native-aot/
